# Where is Interrupt Vector Table stored in ATmega32A?

Tags: avr, embedded, interrupts

Given that Atmega32A has three types of memory : 
1) SRAM.
2) Flash (Program memory).
3)EEPROM.
In which section the Interrupt Vector Table is stored ?

Comment: Is this homework question?

Comment: No, it isn't . I was trying to enrich my knowledge.

Comment: It's just that info is very easy to find in the datasheet, so it just gave an impression as if it was a homework question with no effort trying to find the answer.

Comment: I'm kind of new to this field and I didn't know what to begin with. I could somehow guess it but I needed a crystal clear answer from experts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is stored right at the beginning of flash memory. If you open a binary program image ("`.bin`") using a hex editor, you can see it at the start of the file.

Comment: Program memory, yes.  And *normally* the start of it.  But the IVSEL bit (guarded by the IVCE bit) in the MCUCR allows a runtime switch to a vector table at the start of the bootloader section instead, and the size of the bootloader section can be configured by fuses, so there are actually a variety of possible locations.  But most bootloaders would not use interrupts (would keep them disabled and poll the UART or whatever), so the start of programming memory is indeed the usual place for the vectors, both at rest and in operation.

Comment: Thank you very much !